# Is it possible to deploy one authentication mechanism for two asp.net mvc projects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am learning asp.net mvc and I have few questions that confused me.
Can I have one authentication mechanism for the two projects in one solution?
How can i make lets say the second project in my solution as subdomain in development phase for example support.mydomain/localhost?

Comment: What is your mvc version?

Answer (score 0):

you can implement this by using either one of the both ways :
1. physically separate the logic of asp.net identity models and controllers into a separate project, and then add the reference for the output result in each of your apps.
Note here view will be maintained separately inside each of your UI layer (MVC projects)

2. the other way is smellier to the first approach but the type of project will be a web service, so each new web project will consume authentication and authorization by accessing this web service.